# onpointermove event is not firing up for textbox in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11

onpointermove event is not firing up for textbox in IE11 in window 8.1 phone. onpointerup and onpointerdown event is firing up properly but not onpointermove.

Here is the fiddle to reproduce the issue,

http://jsfiddle.net/ph0v7reu/6/

```
document.getElementById("test").onpointerup = function handle1(event){
    var result = document.getElementById("result");
    result.value = event.type;
    return true;
};

document.getElementById("test").onpointermove = function handle2(event){
    var result = document.getElementById("result");
    result.value = event.type;
    return true;
};

document.getElementById("test").onpointerdown = function handle3(event){
    var result = document.getElementById("result");
    result.value = event.type;
    return true;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not seeing pointermove events because the move is being interpreted as a pan gesture.  Use the touch-action property to disable panning on the element and you should start to receive pointermove events instead.

```
input { touch-action: none; }
```

For more, you can see a recent talk I gave on this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l8upftEWslM#t=1136

Relevant part of the standard for this: http://www.w3.org/TR/pointerevents/#declaring-candidate-regions-for-default-touch-behaviors

Answer (score 0):

Use the non-prefixed lowercase name, pointermove, which is better for standards compliance and future compatibility

So your code should be:

```
document.getElementById("test").pointermove = function handle2(event){
```

Comment: "pointermove" is to be used if we are adding EventListener, like object.addEventListener("pointermove", handler, useCapture)

Answer (score 0):

It seems mobile versions of IE10 and IE11 have a lot of bugs when some ediitable area gets focus.

Under editable area are meant: `<textarea>, <input type="text">` or similar, and div with contentEditable attribute.

IE10 has a bug, that when the editable area gets focus, any element with registered msPointerDown event handler does not get fired.

This can be at least partially workarounded, since msPointerMove is fired, so at least you can assume by checking isPrimary on msPointerMove event that first finger has touched the area. Any additional touches are processed correctly with msPointerDown event.

Now IE11, same issue... It processes pointerdown correctly during focus, but does not fire pointermove. This can be partially worked around by replacing pointermove by a touchmove event, at least with latest IE11 upgrade that began to support touch events (even if absolutely full crap implementation of TouchEvent).

I believe the day will never come when the IE programmers begin to write good software. Unfortunally there is no one good alternate browser for Microsoft Mobile systems.